# will the path or callback be executed first in fs.unlink?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js, and I do not understand the documentation for the [fs.unlink()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsunlinkpath-callback) function:

> The asynchronous form always takes a completion callback as its last argument. The arguments passed to the completion callback depend on the method, but the first argument is always reserved for an exception.
> If the operation was completed successfully, then the first argument will be null or undefined.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});
```

Which argument will be executed first – the callback or the path? Why was the first argument reserved for an exception?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is here. `err` is just a parameter that indicates whether there was an error with the `fs.unlink()` operation. If it's set, then `err`  is the Error object containing information about the error. If it's not set, the operation was successful. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 10):

This is common pattern for Node.js I/O API functions. It might be easier to understand if you write your code like this

```
const fs = require('fs');

var resultHandler = function(err) { 
    if(err) {
       console.log("unlink failed", err);
    } else {
       console.log("file deleted");
    }
}

console.log("about to call unlink");
fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', resultHandler);
console.log("called unlink");
```

When this code is executed you'll see it to print out

```
about to call unlink
called unlink
file deleted   (or unlink failed if operation ecountered an error)
```

The callback function `resultHandler`is called by Node.js API after I/O operation was completed, this may happen long time after calling the API function. First argument to the callback function is `err` that is null if there was no error, otherwise it has the error message.

Comment: Who is going to pass the **err** argument ? How can I know how many parameters should be in my callback function and for what reason ? Thanks

Comment: unlink word is confusing! It is actually deleting the file from the location. Where does the file go after deletion? I cant find it in trash or /tmp/ !!

Comment: Actually "deleting" a file is just unlinking it from the filesystem. Then the OS will be able to write over that place on the disk since it has no active links.